# Low-pass filter to delay pull-up on powerup

Tags: delay, low-pass, pullup

I would like to integrate a [Si4703 breakout board](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/General/Si4703_Eval_v13.pdf) into a project. I’m only going to use its two-wire interface, without much intelligence to drive any of the other pins. Therefore, I need to initiate the startup sequence with the most primitive means; my intention is to initiate it every time the circuit is powered up. (Resetting the thing during operation is not really a requirement—if at all, it’s OK to require a power cycle for that.)

As part of the startup sequence, I need to keeep `RST_n` low for at least <del>300 ns</del> 30 ns after powerup, then pull it high (and keep it high). The board has an internal 10 kΩ pull-down resistor on that pin, with an extra 330 Ω resistor between the pin and the header (see linked schematic).

While some sources suggest playing with the impedance of the pull-up resistor, increasing it to introduce a delay before the threshold is reached, I am wondering if a low-pass filter is maybe a better idea.

I figured that for a delay of `t`, I would need to aim for a cutoff frequency of `f = 1 / (2 t)`.

Assuming I’d use an RC filter with a 1 kΩ resistor (1/10 of the internal pull-down resistor), I would then need a 10 pF capacitor to get within the neighborhood of the delay I aimed for.

Is this going to work as intended, or am I making a mistake here? Especially, are my calculations quantitatively correct? (Admittedly, I’m more a software than a hardware guy…)

Comment: Weird they would say /RST is pulled low enabling the IC and the converse for SEN on the schematic.

Comment: But your idea is basically sound. Pretty classic reset actually.